# How to model Phase noise?

Tags: signal-processing, digital-communications, matlab, fft, radar

I want to model phase noise. Code below shows how I am adding phase noise in the signal. However, i am not getting correct output. That means, the signal sprectrum shoud be spreading in the frequency domain however, its not changing the phase of the signal. please, anyone can tell me how to model phase noise.

```
sigma = 0.5;
t = 0:0.01:1;
sig  = cos(2*pi*4*t);                                                        % original signal
A = sigma *randn(1,length(t));                                          % standard deviation of phase noise
sig2 = (A) .* cos(2*pi*4*t + sigma*randn(1,length(t)));           % signal with phase noise & amplitud4e noise
figure,plot(t,sig,'r',t,sig2, 'b');
figure, plot(abs(fft(sig,10*length(sig))));    %%% takin absolute value of fft and zero padding
figure, plot(abs(fft(sig2,10*length(sig2))));
return
```

Answer (score 4):

Does this example prove to you that the spectrum spreads ?
The spectral plot uses dB (I find that more convenient) on the Y-axis, so consider it a logarithmic scale.

You can see that I need to add A LOT of noise to the phase.
I think this has to do with the fact that the noise I add is white noise.
In practical solutions this noise usually has a 1/f character near the carrier.

I used Octave for this as I do not have Matlab available (and Octave works for me and is free :-) )

```
clear all;clc;

Fin =1;
Ttotal = 1000;
nop = 100000;

Tsample = Ttotal/nop;
t = 0:Tsample:Ttotal;
Fsample = nop/Ttotal;

x  = sin(2*pi*Fin*t); 
xn  = sin(2*pi*Fin*(t + 0.1*randn(size(t))));

subplot(2, 1, 1);
points = 500;
plot(Fsample*t(1:points),xn(1:points),'r',Fsample*t(1:points),x(1:points),'b')
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(nop); % Next power of 2 from length of y
SX  = fft(x,NFFT)/nop;
SXn = fft(xn,NFFT)/nop;
dBSX = 20 * log( abs(SX));
dBSXn = 20 * log( abs(SXn));
f = Fsample/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
subplot(2, 1, 2);
plot(f,dBSXn(1:NFFT/2+1),'r',f,dBSX(1:NFFT/2+1),'b')
axis([0.5,1.5,-200,0]);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi IC_designer, thanks for your reply. But when i take fft of your signal and phase noise added signal. the spectrum in frequency domain remains the same.

Comment: I think the spectrum changes, see the bottom half of the included plot. The blue trace is the signal without noise, the red one with noise. Close to the carrier the signal is similar but far from the carrier the noise floor increases. What do you expect to see ??

Comment: Hi IC_designer_Rimpelbekkie, I expect to see the broadning of spectrum. Since the phase noise creates broading at both sides of center frequency, i expect to see spectrum broadning in frequency domain. I have created an ideal simulation of fmcw radar and want to make it non ideal therefore want to add phase noise and amplitude noise.

Comment: Ha, I also work on (FMCW) radar :-) I think you're on the right way but you will need to add 1/f noise to the signal. The 1/f character takes care of frequency spreading close to the carrier which is what you want to see. This is also how the noise in oscillators behave. If you google on "phasenoise" some interesting articles can be downloaded. These will explain the 1/f behaviour of phasenoise.

Comment: ahh Perfect. there is a file exchange in mathworks for phase noise.http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8844-phase-noise However, in that as well i am not getting correct output. I desperatly need this solution since I have deadline for my thesis :P

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a subject that can easily be understood in a short time :-( Did you make your input signal long enough so that you get the required frequency resolution after FFT ? Generating a 1/f (pink noise) in time domain also does not seem that obvious to me :-(

Comment: yes. my input signal is long enough. I am refering to a literature(http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-03659-5_7) now for the modelling phase noise.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do so by these steps:

1. Take fft of the original signal.
2. Add noise as an exponential term (by multiplication).
3. Take inverse fft, as noisy signal.

   ```
   close all
   sigma = 10;
   t = 0:0.01:1;
   sig  = cos(2*pi*4*t);      % original signal
   A = sigma *randn(1,length(t));  % standard deviation of phase noise
   fftsig=fft(sig);
   fftsig2=fftsig.*exp(A*1i); %adding noise
   sig2=ifft(fftsig2);% signal with phase noise
   ```

[image: summary of results]

another way maybe:

```
   sigma = 100;
   t = 0:0.01:10;
   sig  = cos(2*pi*4*t);      % original signal
   sig3 = cos(2*pi*4*t+sigma *randn(1,length(t)));
```

[image]

Comment: HI SMA.D. Thanks for your reply. if you see the fft of both signals than it 's same. There shoud be spreading of specrtrum when I add phase noise in the signal.

Comment: Edited! maybe...

Comment: Thanks SMA.D. But this I have already done. I mean the way you edited.